# All includes are pointing at local host

Tags: localhost

I have just transfered my wordpress site from a local host to my web host via FTP.

I can load up my home page using my domain but no CSS or JS are being loaded, looking at the console I can see it cant retrive the files as it is adding http://localhost/ in front of every file path.

Where can i go in to change all of these?

Sorry for the basic question i am quite new to wordpress.

Comment: Do a search in your files for `http://localhost/`

Comment: Is there a way to search every file at the same time for that phrase otherwise it will take hours to open every file

Comment: have you updated your urls after website transfer?

Comment: No, do I have to do that in admin page? Sorry I have never migrated a Wordpress site before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have to update your website URLs after migrating your site from live server to local or local to live server.

Go to your `phpmyadmin` and select your database, then in **SQL** section paste the following codes (replace `http://www.oldurl.com` to your localhost URL and `http://www.newurl.com` to your existing live domain URL, do it carefully) and click Go.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

It will replace your localhost URL with your new Live domain URL.

After that go to `Settings > Permalinks` then just click Update/Save button then  check your website & its internal pages, make sure you quit your localhost so you can see if URLs are now updated & not.

**Keep in mind**

you may still have to change some URLs in your website content **may be** which you've put.

**Method 2**

There is also a plugin called [Velvet Blues Update Urls](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/), install & activate it then go to `Tools > Update URLs` then do the same put old url in old section and New live to New url section check all the boxes except **Guid** then click update, but its not guaranteed that all URLs will be updated.

I suggest run the above queries first, then you can also try this plugin as well.